# How to enable JMX statistics for infinispan 2LC in Jboss EAP 6.2

Tags: hibernate, jmx, infinispan, jboss-eap-6, hibernate-cache

I have enabled 2LC in my application deployed over JBoss EAP 6.2 using infinispan.
I want to measure performance gain and want to enable JMX statistics for infinispan to see cache hits/misses etc. 
In EAP 6.3 onwards we can add statistics-enabled="true" for cache and cache container. but that doesn't work for 6.2.
Any similar configuration for JBoss 6.2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statistics are automatically enabled in EAP 6.2.  Rather 6.2 lacks the ability to disable statistics.